# PXE Boot laptop doesn't send out DHCP discover

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, wireshark, sccm, wds

ultimately im trying to get a PXE boot laptop to talk to the WDS server. While monitoring the switch using wireshark from laptop #2, it doesn't see ANY DHCP packet during a PXE boot. whereas, I would boot the PXE laptop normally to windows and i can see the DHCP packet.

I am using 'dhcp' as the display filter in wireshark.

i thought it was so strange to not see any DHCP packet when PXE booting... could someone shed a light?

Here's my topology:
[topology image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGF8U.png)

Answer (score 0):

What error are you seeing on the PXE boot screen of the laptop?

Have you checked your router configuration for IP Helper setup, as described in the article below:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4468612/troubleshoot-pxe-boot-issues-in-configuration-manager

This article gives a detailed description of how to check your PXE boot setup including log files to check & network trace examples:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4468601/pxe-boot-in-configuration-manager

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! the link to the 2nd article helped out. turns out there was a setting with the DHCP scope.

Answer (score 0):

try filtering by `bootp` instead